# Make loops not hang the browser

Tags: javascript, loops, blocking

Is it possible to make `for` and `while` loops not hang the browser while synchronizing asynchronous operations?

I'm asking this because synchronous `XMLHttpRequest` only blocks UI events, but doesn't hang the browser entirely. I would like to have the same behavior of loops.

Comment: If your loops is making the browser hang, you should probably figure out what you're doing that takes that long inside the loop before you try making them async. As a sidenote, setTimeout can be used for remarkable things.

Comment: I want to block execution of my function until something happens. Async can't block functions.

Comment: What you are saying in the question and what you left in comments contradict each other. There is no wait/sleep in JavaScript.

Comment: Don't forget [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers)!

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be going about the problem a bit wrong. JavaScript is single threaded, so you do not want to have something "block" while it's waiting for a condition. Instead, you want to utilize a callback to alert the function that you're done doing whatever it is you're doing.

For instance, let's say you have the following common scenario: Your page has a "submit" button which validates data, then asks if the user is sure they want to continue, then submits the data. You might imagine the code looks like this:

```
function clickSubmit() {
    //validate data
    //show confirmation dialog
    //block until "OK" or "Cancel" is clicked
    //if OK, submit
    //else cancel
}
```

Of course, that wouldn't really work because the user would not be able to click OK or Cancel while your function is blocking. So instead, you would make use of a callback to handle the situation. Something more like this:

```
function clickSubmit() {
    //validate data
    dialogOK.onclick = function () {
        //submit
    }
    dialogCancel.onclick = function () {
        //cancel
    }
    //show confirmation dialog
}
```

That way, the function will give up the one and only JS execution thread as soon as the dialog is shown, but then effectively resume execution once confirm or cancel is selected by the user. Use of closure scope allows you to create a persistent execution context so that you don't "lose track" of your data, even though the function is giving up the CPU to other tasks.

Real life may require some tweaking based on the specific situation, but this is the general structure you can use to achieve the functionality it appears you need.

Hopefully I understood your question. It's a little sparse on the details.

And by the way, the way `XMLHttpRequest` does it is by making use of native browser functionality. It doesn't actually need to "block" while waiting for a response, though. It can simply tell the browser engine to send an HTTP request and then notify it once a response shows up. Very much similar to how AJAX works in practice.

Comment: Callbacks are what I **don't** want to have. I'm searching for something to avoid use of callbacks. And, _synchronous_ `XMLHttpRequest` blocks UI, but doesn't hang the browser completely, that's what I want to replicate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible using `setTimeout` and `setInterval` by which you periodically give control to the browser to prevent 'hanging'. You can take a look at the [jQuery ASync plugin](http://mess.genezys.net/jquery/jquery.async.php)

Comment: Can you make them pause/resume execution of a function?

Comment: Technically, yes you can. You can call `setTimeout` to call your function with certain parameters and the parameters can help you decide where to 'continue' your function.

Comment: That's what I want to get rid of.

Comment: If you mean pause the execution of a function and resume the function after a few seconds without hanging the browser, it is not possible. The reason is that javascript is single threaded - you cannot give control to the browser (so that it can do its stuff and prevent hanging) unless you return from the function. The browser will wait until you return.

Comment: But how does `XMLHttpRequest` not hang the browser?